# MySQL query with JOIN gives always a result

Tags: mysql, join

This is the query:

```
SELECT `absences`.`absences_ID`,start, end, half_day, `employee`.`cts`, `employee`.`name`, `employee`.`surname`
FROM `employee` LEFT JOIN
     `login`.`absences`
     ON `employee`.`employee_ID` = `absences`.`employee_FK`
 WHERE cts = 111113 and MONTH(start) = '1' and YEAR(start) ='2015' and inactive = 0 and type_FK = 2 OR type_FK = 3
```

And here is my ERM:

[image]

When I run this query I always get a result, even when I'm sure that there is no result. If I run this query it always shows the same result:

```
absences_ID start   end half_day    cts name    surname
2   2015-07-08  2015-07-08  0   111113  Test    1234
```

What is wrong with my query? Is there a problem with the JOIN?

Comment: do you want left or inner join??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause is not doing what you expect, because you need parentheses.  However, you can also fix it just by using `in`:

```
 WHERE cts = 111113 and MONTH(start) = '1' and YEAR(start) ='2015' and
       inactive = 0 and type_FK in (2, 3)
```

Your version is parsed as:

```
 WHERE (cts = 111113 and MONTH(start) = '1' and YEAR(start) ='2015' and
        inactive = 0 and type_FK = 2) or
       (type_FK = 3)
```

Also note that if any of the columns in the `where` come from `absences`, then the `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`, because the `NULL` values fails the conditions.